# How to store key with NULL value in JSON database field by laravel?

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel, eloquent

Imagine this :

```
<input name="bank[account]">
<input name="bank[name]">
<input name="bank[status]">
```

All of this fields store in on column in DB as JSON.

I used Laravel `$casts` to introduce this field as an array:

```
protected $casts = [
    'bank' => 'array',
]
```

Now the problem is all `bank[]` filed is `nullable` and when user didn't fill some of that, nothing stored in DB and when i try to show stored value to users i got `Undefined index` error.

I need to store `Empty` or `NULL` input fields in DB like this `"Key":NULL`. in this case it should be like this :

```
{"name":NULL,"account":NULL,"status":NULL}
```

I use [Laravel 5.7](https://laravel.com/) and [Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation) to process my forms.

Comment: Add your DB migration for that table to your question.

Comment: $table->json('bank')->nullable();             // JSON : Name; Card; Account;

Answer (score 0):

Solution :
Just by using this middleware

```
\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
```

notice : this middleware is one of default laravel middlewares. you don't need to do anything to use this. 
I don't know why it doesn't work at first but worked after a while without changing anything !!!